# Why Cypher query returns a null value in average function?

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I am working with a Neo4j (2.2.0 M2) embedded graph application. For query this graph I use the Cypher way, using the GraphDatabaseService class and its method `execute(query, params)`, wich returns a `org.neo4j.graphdb.Result` instance. The problem is when I use a aggregated function (avg) in the query:

```
MATCH 
(e:Person {person_id: {id} }) <-[:ASIGNED_TO]-(t:Task) 
WHERE t.start_date >= {cuttof_date} 
RETURN AVG(t.estimated_time) as avgte
```

For briefly understand of this query: id and cuttof_date are parameters I put then in a Mapset, last of them is a date in UTC (long) and comparable.
The result of this query, using the Neo4j browser manager, and giving some values to the specified parameters, is the following:

avgte

6.166666666666667

Returned 1 row in 665 ms.

Perfect!, now, when I expect the same result using Cypher in the Java code (I have avoided "try", and "with resources"):

```
    //Same params
    int id  = 187;
    long longDate = 1357016400000L;

    Map<String,Object> params= new HashMap<>();
    params.put("id", id);
    params.put("cuttof_date", longDate);

    //same query
    String query = "MATCH"+
      "(e:Person {person_id: {id} }) <-[:ASIGNED_TO]-(t:Task) " +
      "WHERE t.start_date >= {cuttof_date} " +
      "RETURN AVG(t.estimated_time) as avgte"; 

    GraphDatabaseService gdbs = new 
                GraphDatabaseFactory().
                newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_NAME) ;

    Result result = gdbs.execute(query, params);
    Map<String, Object> firstRow = result.next();
    Object avgteObject = firstRow.get("avgte");

    //Using the most basic transformation: as String
    System.out.println("AVGTE: "+String.valueOf(avgteObject));
```

The result is: "AVGTE: null". How can this be possible!? Also I've used other classes like `ExtendedExecutionResult`, and `ExecutionResult` from `org.neo4j.cypher package`, but also returns the same output. The problem is not the Query, it works perfectly so I think it is when using the Cypher classes, it doesn't load the value of the aggregated function.

Any ideas??

Comment: Are you sure DB_NAME points correctly to your database? If the database folder doesn't exists neo4j will silently create empty database, hence your null result.

Comment: Yeap, everything about database configuration is OK. The DB_NAME var contains a correctly String with the specified database location. Also, with this same codeI have executed another queries, and they work.

Comment: Thanks @frant.hartm, that was the problem, an empty database creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad: creating a empty database. The snipet code: DB_NAME takes the following value: "gespro_graph_db"

```
GraphDatabaseService gdbs = new 
                GraphDatabaseFactory().
                newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_NAME) ;
```

It works if the graph database location is in the same project path, but it is in folder structure like this: /project_path/gespro_graph/gespro_graph_db/, where last folder is the real location. My project was pointing to /project_path/gespro_graph_db, and this is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you have an node without `estimated_time` property in your db?

Try to return `t` or `t.estimated_time` to see the raw data

Comment: Michael, first of all thanks for your answer, really I was expecting it. trying you solution I found a empty resultset. That doesn't solve my problem, but I release that the graph database was empty. As @frant.hartm said a empty database was created, and consequently a null response. Creating a new project, and checking every step, the result of avg function did work perfectly!!! The problem: bad location of graph database. I think Neo4j Community must fix this kind of database creation to prevent this issue.